# Add validation to a checkout field from my module

Tags: magento2

I know I can add validations in the `checkout_index_index.xml` like this:

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-jurgis" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
```

I could just override this file from my module, but I am looking for a more flexible way to do this.

Is there a way to just "add" the validation to a checkout field without overriding the entire `checkout_index_index.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like:

`Module/Namespace/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                   <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                           <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                   <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                               <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                   <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
                                                                               </item>
                                                                           </item>
                                                                           <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                              <item name="your-validation" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                          </item>
                                                                   </item>
                                                               </item>
                                                           </item>
                                                       </item>
                                                   </item>
                                               </item>
                                           </item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </argument>
               </arguments>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
```

In this example, you add it to the telephone field, but I'm sure you can see the pattern.